# How to embed images in IDv3 tags in mp3 files in android using any library or not

Tags: android, mp3, embed, albumart, mp3agic

I am trying to **embed images** in mp3 files to make it the album art of the music file and replace the old one. I tried using **mp3agic** library but it is not working. Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is _"it is not working"_ mean? For example is there an error message? or Did you check the mp3 bytes (in a hex editor) to see if there's JPEG bytes in there (search for hex/bytes `FFD8` and if found then near it you should also see text `JFIF`)... So is it working but your Android code isn't getting the image? or you can't find image at all even with no error in **mp3agic**? I just work with `mp3` bytes but you should put code that helps other `Android` followers to re-produce your issue. Also put an example small mp3 file that is result of **mp3agic** (google free mp3 test file)

Comment: Will check and revert...